# How to form connection string to enable "force protocol encryption" property to use ssl encryption

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, mfc

I am using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server in my MFC application to use database.I want to my connection to use ssl encryption for connection.
My code looks like:

```
         String SQL_connData = "provider=SQLOLEDB;"; 
         SQL_connData += "Encrypt=true;";
         SQL_connData += "TrustServerCertificate=true;"
```

It seems it doesn't use the SSL certificate installed on server machine.
Can somebody let me know how to write the connection string in such case?

Many Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server supports the force encryption property. You will need to use one of the native client providers.

Comment: I am using sqloledb provider and i think its a sql native client provider.Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.Can you please provide code snippet or suggestion ?

Comment: Based on the provider name, it doesn't look like it.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/ , there is no encryption option. vs. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/encrypt-data-sent-over-network/

Comment: If it doesn't support then the connection string written above should fail i guess as it doesn't have "Encrypt" and "TrustServerCertificate" property but the connection is being established sussessfully.

Comment: If it supported them -- it would work -- it is likely ignoring them because it doesn't recognize them. Try changing Encrypt to Decrypt and see what happens.

Comment: Result is still same :(

Comment: You need the right provider.

Comment: I have created a sample app by using both the oledb provider.Find my observation below.

Comment: Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144914/establish-db-connection-by-using-microsoft-ole-db-provider-and-sql-native-ole-db

Comment: Please follow the link below for answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144914/establish-db-connection-by-using-microsoft-ole-db-provider-and-sql-native-ole-db/38290997#38290997

Comment: Microsoft OLEDB provider for SQL Server supports ado properties and provider specific properties. I believe you need to add "Trusted_Connection=true" to provide a security context for the connection. As long as there is a certificate on the client, you should get an SSL or TLS connection. Also, explain what you mean by "certificate installed on the server machine". Do you mean that you installed a certificate and set Force Encryption to yes?