# Establish DB connection by using Microsoft OLE DB provider and SQL Native OLE DB provider

Tags: sql-server, winapi, ssl, encryption, oledbconnection

I have created a sample app by using both the oledb provider(SQLOLEDB and SQL Native OLEDB provider).

Case 1 : Provider = SQLOLEDB

```
hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
hr = cADOConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
CString con_string = "provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MYPC;Database=MyDB";

CString SSlcon_string = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;server=MYPC;Database=MyDB";
CString userName = "sa";
CString Password = "sa";
BSTR bsConnection = /*con_string*/SSlcon_string.AllocSysString();
BSTR uName = userName.AllocSysString();
BSTR uPassword = Password.AllocSysString();

hr = cADOConnection->Open(bsConnection, uName, uPassword, adConnectUnspecified);
printf("connection has been established");
VARIANT vaNoRecords;
memset(&vaNoRecords, 0, sizeof vaNoRecords);
CString sql = "SELECT * FROM salary";
BSTR query = sql.AllocSysString();
_RecordsetPtr rs;
rs = cADOConnection->Execute(query, &vaNoRecords, adCmdText);
printf("connection has been established\n");
```

Result : If certificate is installed on server machine then the connection is secure regardless of enabling
Encrypt=true and TrustServerCertificate=true from in connection string.

Case 2 : Provider = SQLNCLI10.1(SQL native client oledb provider)

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
hr = cADOConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
CString con_string = "provider=SQLNCLI10.1;server=MYPC;Database=MyDB";

CString SSlcon_string = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;server=MYPC;Database=MyDB";
CString userName = "sa";
CString Password = "sa";
BSTR bsConnection = con_string/*SSlcon_string*/.AllocSysString();
BSTR uName = userName.AllocSysString();
BSTR uPassword = Password.AllocSysString();
hr = cADOConnection->Open(bsConnection, uName, uPassword, adConnectUnspecified);
printf("connection has been established");
VARIANT vaNoRecords;
memset(&vaNoRecords, 0, sizeof vaNoRecords);
CString sql = "SELECT suppliernumber, name1 FROM zrs_supplier";
BSTR query = sql.AllocSysString();
_RecordsetPtr rs;
rs = cADOConnection->Execute(query, &vaNoRecords, adCmdText);
printf("connection has been established\n");
```

Result : If certificate is installed on server machine then the connection is secure regardless of enabling
Encrypt=true and TrustServerCertificate=true from in connection string.i.e Result is same as above.

In both the case i am getting same behavior.Am i missing something here??
Any Suggestion would be appreciated ?? 
 [Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122323/how-to-form-connection-string-to-enable-force-protocol-encryption-property-to?noredirect=1#comment63713081_38122323)

---

Comment: So, everything is working out fine. What is your question? Appending question marks to a statement (e.g. *"Any Suggestion would be appreciated"*) doesn't turn it into a question. Adding more won't change that.

Comment: The question is tagged at the end as "Original question" :) I am using both SQLOLE DB provider to establist sql connection. I want to established SSL connection. No idea how to do that.I installed self signed certificate on sql server and able to make the SSL connection but i want only my MFC client to use the certificate and setup SSL connection.

Comment: My MFC client is not telling to establish a secure connection even though SSL connection is being established if certificate is installed.I want only my MFC client to validate the certificate and establish the SSL connection.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the connection string with

```
CString SSlcon_string = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Use Encryption for Data=True;server=MYPC;Database=MyDB";
```

The remaining steps will be same.Install the same certificate(present on server)  on client machine's "**truted root certificate authorities**" folder.

If server and client both will have same certificate then connection will be established(SSL Connection) otherwise fail.